# Advance steel api commit();

Tags: c#, autodesk

i'am starting to work with advance steel api and cann't start the transaction with the program visual studio DocumentAccess class doesn't contain Commit() Method

Error   CS1061  'DocumentAccess' does not contain a definition for 'Commit' and no accessible extension method 'Commit' accepting a first argument of type 'DocumentAccess' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

i'am starting to work with advance steel api and cann't start the transaction with the program visual studio DocumentAccess class doesn't contain Commit() Method

Error   CS1061  'DocumentAccess' does not contain a definition for 'Commit' and no accessible extension method 'Commit' accepting a first argument of type 'DocumentAccess' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of DocumentAcces use Transaction

```
DocumentManager.LockCurrentDocument();
Transaction trans = TransactionManager.StartTransaction();
//your code
trans.Commit();
DocumentManager.UnlockCurrentDocument();
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you use the correct `DocumentAccess`

Assembly `ASObjectsMgd, Version=...., Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null`

NameSpace `Autodesk.AdvanceSteel.DocumentManagement`

the Asesmbly is located in `C:\ProgramFiles\Autodesk\AutoCAD [Release]\ADVS\`  do not copy the Reference to the output directory - it shouldn't harm, since Autocad loads it before your Applicationplugin would do, but it would mess up your output directory...

AND:

since it implements `IDisopsable` always use it  with a `using`-Clause